# Dll export symbol of function from static linked library

Tags: c++, dll, dllexport

I am wrapping a static library in Dll to hide a lot of the implementation stuff since only 4-5 functions are needed and to avoid providing all third-party libraries and many header files. I seem to be having an issue with exporting a function to the dll from the static lib.
The static lib has settings classes / structs similar to the one below

```
struct FooSettings
{
   bool Read(const std::string& file); // implemented in .cpp
   bool Write(const std::string& file); // implemented in .cpp
   // rest members, just plain types
};
```

In the Dll side

```
#include "FooSettings.h"

#if defined(WIN32) || defined(_WIN32)
    #if defined(LIB_EXPORT)
        // DLL Build, exporting symbols
        #define LIB_API __declspec(dllexport)
    #elif LIB_IMPORT
        // DLL use, importing symbols
        #define LIB_API __declspec(dllimport)
    #endif
#endif

#ifndef LIB_API
    #define LIB_API
#endif

class LIB_API LibSDK
{
public:
    LibSDK();
    ~LibSDK();

    FooSettings get() const noexcept;
    void set(const FooSettings& settings) const noexcept;

    void dummy() 
    {
        foo.Read("");
    }

private:
    // etc...
};
```

I can call `dummy()` on the "client" side without any issues
but the code below leads to unresolved symbols

```
FooSettings foo;
foo.Read("");
```

I would have expected that the FooSettings:Read is at least exported since it is part of a dummy function. Am I missing something ? My preference is to export it without the dummy function but I dont seem to be able to make it work either way.

Comment: How do you export functions? Why there are no `__declspec(dllexport)` in your code? Are you using export file? You should post the full code. Also if you need to export `Read` function, you can do it without exproting `dummy`. There is no relation between the two.

Comment: @Ivan I have edited my post to show how I export the class, as you said it is pretty much using __declspec(dllexport) by defining LIB_EXPORT. The problem is from the class function that is part of the static library

Comment: So you are exporting a `LibSDK` class (tihs includes `dummy` function, but you are not exporting `FooSettings`. Do you expect `FooSettings` to be exported automatically? Or do you want to export `LibSDK` without exporting `FooSettings`? In this case `dummy` should no be `inline` function.

Comment: @Ivan, The FooSettings function is part of the static library so there is no point in exporting it. As far as I am aware and from https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140321-00/?p=1433, you either need a .def file or you need to create a dummy function. So in this case I was trying a dummy function. I was assuming that since the dummy function can see the symbol to call the Read and Write then I should be able to do so from the "client" side but that resulted in unresolved symbol. Of course the dummy function was in the .cpp file but over here I added it all together for brevity.

Comment: I should say that yes I know that if I add all the static library files in the Dll project and export the FooSettings class then it all works fine as one would expect. I was just wondering if I could avoid doing so and force the symbols to be added in a different way. I also read that you can do it with \Includes in the linker properties but I could not figure the syntax.

Comment: I don't get what you are trying to achieve. If `Read` is not exported, then client cannot call it directly. Client can call `dummy` and it will call `Read`, but that's it. `Read` is not exported in your example.

Comment: What I am trying to do is pretty much export the Read and Write functions of the FooSettings class that is part of the static library to the Dll. According to the msdn link I provided it should just be `" a dummy function that calls the function you want to export. That dummy function will trigger the resolution of the symbol from the static library, ..."` It just does not seem to work even if I mark the struct with LIB_API

Comment: Ok, I got it. It doesn't work like this. To export a function you need to put a `dllexport` on it. What you are citing is about linking object files of a static library, not about exporting functions from DLL.

Comment: hmmm, `struct LIB_API FooSettings` and move `#include "FooSettings.h"` just before `class LIB_API LibSDK`? Or maybe use an export file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coming back to all this, the answer was actually to #define LIB_EXPORT in the static library build as well which I did not expect.

I did not think that such a thing would be needed for a static .lib files since all they are is just a bundle of object files so they did not need to be marked for export. Apparently, it was needed if you want to export the functions from the static lib to your wrapper dll.